# Play button on ViewVideo

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how to put a play button on the viewVideo on my layout. Also do I have to put something on my layout for it to work?

Here's my code:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    VideoView resultvideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.videorec);
        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }

    public void dispatchTakeVideoIntent(View v) {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);

            resultvideo.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout.

Specify a drawable you can see in FrameLayout children. and use Foreground Drawable to draw the button with a drawable:

```
myFrameLayout.setForegroundDrawable(myPlayDrawable);
```